# MySql Query error in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.4. When trying to run

```
select * from `users` inner join `addprojects` on `users`.`emp_id` = `addprojects`.`emp_id` where `emp_id` = $emp_id)"
```

It produces:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'emp_id'
>   in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `users` inner join
>   `addprojects` on `users`.`emp_id` = `addprojects`.`emp_id` where
>   `emp_id` = $emp_id)"

```
$emp_id= Auth::user()->emp_id;
$projects_for_emp = DB::table('users')->join('addprojects', 'users.emp_id', '=', 'addprojects.emp_id')->where('emp_id', '$emp_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emp_id`  in both tables , so can use `users.emp_id` or `addprojects.emp_id`

```
->where('users.emp_id', '=', $emp_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have specified column name which exists in both tables, so use `users.emp_id` or `addprojects.emp_id` doesn't matter which one

Example:

```
$emp_id= Auth::user()->emp_id;
$projects_for_emp = DB::table('users')
   ->join('addprojects', 'users.emp_id', '=', 'addprojects.emp_id')
   ->where('users.emp_id', '$emp_id')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because both users and addprojects tables have same named field "emp_id".
You can change your code like following.

```
$emp_id= Auth::user()->emp_id;
$projects_for_emp = DB::table('users')
    ->join('addprojects', 'users.emp_id', '=', 'addprojects.emp_id')
    ->where('users.emp_id', $emp_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks it works. but i think where condition does not work properly . If I  return $projects_for_emp; It shows jeson word with blank page. But If I 
->where('users.emp_id', '245') , It will Show value